# Symfony single controller as service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Is it possible to make symfony single controller as service

I am trying to make a single controller as service not the whole bundle

code which i have tried is in service.yml (CMSBundle)

```
cms.exampleController:
    class: Website\CMSBundle\Controller\ExampleController
    autowire: true
```

and trying to inject the service from a bundle which is already service, public and autowrie true

example in controller

```
namespace Website\CMSBundle\Controller;

use Common\UtilityBundle\Listener\ContactData; (UtilityBundle in this every thing is service)
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
  public function testAction(Request $oRequest, ContactData $oContactData)
  {
    //this will become error because $oContactData is always null
  }
}
```

error message

```
Controller "Website\CMSBundle\Controller\ExampleController::testAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$oContactData" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.
```

My routes

```
example_details:
  path: /test
  defaults: { _controller: WebsiteCMSBundle:Example:test, eventId:null }
```

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. What is not working exactly (error message)? Maybe you are missing the route definition?

Comment: As a minimum you need to tag your controller service with controller.service_arguments in order for your action arguments to be resolved.  I would also replace cms.exampleController with the full class name.  If you still have problems then show your routing.  I don't have a 3.4 setup handy but you will need to convince the router to use the service and not just instantiate a new controller.  Which it does by default.

Comment: @cread i have added my routes

Comment: Actually, it is still not using the controller service with the route you showed.  You will probably get an error if you try something like $this->render().  Update your route with _controller: 'Website\CMSBundle\Controller\ExampleController::test' and make sure you also updated the controller's service id.  By the way, this should all be in the docs.  Search for "using controllers as services".